Field Calculating ArcGIS Online
I would like to add the same value to an entire column of an ArcGIS Online hosted feature layer. ArcGIS Pro will not allow me to field calculate a hosted feature layer. What are my alternatives?

Do you have edit access to the feature layer?   Can you manually change a single value in the Attributes Table?

Open the hosted feature layer in ArcGIS Online (in the web browser), then click the 'Data' tab to view the data as a table.  Left click the field name in the table header and choose 'Calculate' from the pop-up menu that appears.
From there you can select 'Arcade' or 'SQL' as the language to use to define your field calculation.
Eg, using Arcade to add 5 to all records for a a field named Blah, you could use the expression:
$feature.Blah + 5
NB:  This requires that you have edit access to the feature layer!  If you do not have edit access, then you cannot modify the values in either Pro or Online.
